# Updating $scope in function and $apply dosen't works

Tags: angularjs, scope

I have problem with updating input value. I have $scope.date_from which is displayed in input[type="data"]. I want to update value in it by clicking some button. My code here:

```
$scope.update_date = function (date_from, date_to) {
        $scope.date_from=date_from;
        $scope.date_to=date_to;
        console.log($scope.date_from);
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.date_from=date_from;
            $scope.date_to=date_to;
        });
    }
```

The problem is that value is updated in input[type="date"] after clicking my button but it is not displayed (I only see changed in code). My button look like this:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="update_date('2017-02-13', '2017-02-13')">Today</a>
```

Comment: "The problem is that value is updated in input[type="date"]" . What do you mean by that ? Also could you provide the input element ?

Comment: I mean that value in input is updated by this function but there is no visual update. In chrome dev tools I see in code that value is updated but I can't see it on my page.

My input:
`<input type="date" name="date_from" value="{{ date_from | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}" ng-model="date_from">
   <input type="date" name="date_to" value="{{ date_to | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}" ng-model="date_to">`

Comment: Provide more code. I mean your HTML input type where you are binding it.

Comment: The answer given by @Korte should work i think. There is nothing a problem except converting your value into Date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert your date `string` to `Date` object. No need of `$scope.$apply()`.

Just like this:

```
$scope.update_date = function(date_from, date_to) {
    $scope.date_from = new Date(date_from);
    $scope.date_to = new Date(date_to);
  }
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6phm4yg/)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Don't know why. It works on fiddle as I wanted to.
EDIT: Oh wait. It works :) Thank you!